# I have a String[] to arraylist homework assignment

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Here is the code I wrote:

```java
public class TestCourse {   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Course course1 = new Course("Data Structures");
    Course course2 = new Course("Database Systems");

    course1.addStudent("Peter Jones");
    course1.addStudent("Brian Smith");
    course1.addStudent("Anne Kennedy");

    course2.addStudent("Peter Jones");
    course2.addStudent("Steve Smith");

    System.out.println("Number of students in course1: "
      + course1.getNumberOfStudents());
    String[] students = course1.getStudents();
    for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++)
      System.out.print(students[i] + ", ");

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Number of students in course2: "
      + course2.getNumberOfStudents());   } }

import java.util.ArrayList; public class Course {

    private String courseName;
    private ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
    private int numberOfStudents;

    public Course(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
    public void addStudent(String name) {
        students.add(name);
        numberOfStudents ++;
    }
    public ArrayList getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
    public int getNumberOfStudents() {
        return numberOfStudents;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }
    public void dropStudents(ArrayList students) {
        this.students = students;
        students.remove(students);
        numberOfStudents --;
    } }
```

I have a error in
`String[] students = course1.getStudents();` in test course.

I tried to put in arraylist, but it didn't work..

Comment: Keep trying - that's what homework is for

Comment: Isn't homework supposed to be done by yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're returning the [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). So fix that. Something like,

```
public ArrayList<String> getStudents() {
    return students;
}
```

Next, you can call [`List.toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29) like

```
String[] students = course1.getStudents().toArray(new String[]{});
```

**or** use the `List` directly, like

```
List<String> students = course1.getStudents();
for (String student : students) {
    // Do something with each student.
}
```